# Check if file is present in some directory in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-handling

I am reading a file from some directory using visual c++. How do i check if that file exists or not.
If i use:

```
file.open("file.txt", ios::in);
```

where file is a member of fstream. This creates a file ifthat file is not present.
How can i check if that file is present or not.
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure? `ios::in` alone should not create the file. Maybe you're passing other flags to `open()`?

Comment: Is WINAPI permitted ? Using `ifstream` or similar is not sufficient to determine if a file exists as the `open()` attempt may fail due to a permissions check.

Comment: @hamidi - I have no idea about flags but ios::in is the only thing that I am using

Answer (score 4):

Your code creates *no* file if that file isn’t already present (on most systems, assuming `file` is a `std::ifstream`).

Due to inherent concurrency in file system access, *there is no reliable way to check whether a file exists*. The best way is simply to open the file for read access and test whether that was successful:

```
if (file.good()) …
// or simply
if (file) …
```

Comment: But before i use good() I will need to use open(), wouldn't I? This will create a file if not present...

Answer (score 2):

```
ifstream my_file("file.txt");
if (my_file.good())
{
  // read away
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on Windows, you can use Windows API to do the job for you. Here is a brief code snippet for you... You have to pass the complete path of file.txt in order for this to succeed. For E.g. D:\MyFolder\file.txt.

```
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

hFind = FindFirstFile("D:\MyFolder\file.txt", &FindFileData);
GetLastError();

    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
          // File not found
```

Answer (score 0):

just calling file like that should not create a file if it is missing. It should fail and succeeding calls to file.is_open() would return false.

Comment: SampleDialog::fileHandler.open("file.txt", ios::in);            if(SampleDialog::fileHandler.is_open()){MessageBox("File opened", NULL, MB_OK);
 this is the code that I am using. The moment open() is called a file gets created if not present. Then is_open() always evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could implement the following:

```
ifstream file("text.text"); 

if(!file){
//handle error / throw exception here
}
```